# Trigger to update Case Status if Status = Waiting on Internal and gets a new FeedComment

Tags: apex, trigger, code, feedcomment

I have this block of code to update case status when we receive a new FeedComment on a case. But I want to update it to only update if the case has a status of "Waiting on Internal" or "Waiting on Client". I am not Apex savy so any help would be appreciated!

```
trigger FeedThis on FeedComment(after insert, after update){

    List<Case> updates = new List<case>();
    List<id> userList = new List<ID>();
    List<Id> feedItemList = new List<id>();
    for(FeedComment fc: trigger.new){
        feedItemList.add(fc.FeedItemId);
        userList.add(fc.InsertedById);
    }
    Map<Id, FeedItem> feedMap = new Map<id, FeedItem>([select id,InsertedById,Visibility from feedItem where Id IN :feedItemList]);
    Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id, User>([select id, usertype, name from user where ID IN :userList]);
    for(FeedComment fc: trigger.new){
        if (feedMap != null && feedMap.containsKey(fc.feedItemId) && fc.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Case.SObjectType ) {
            updates.add(new Case(
                    Id = fc.ParentId,
                    Internal_Case_Status__c = 'Pending'
                    ));
        }
        
    }
    if(updates != null && updates.size() > 0)
    update updates;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part of it isn't working? Please edit your question with more detail about what part of this you're actually stuck on.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this question - Why was [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/401344/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-error-the-semicolon-required-seems-spurious-lwc-javas) question not downvoted ? 

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code.

1. We need to use Set for storing `feedItem` & `User` Ids since records can have same InsertedById.
2. Instead of manually checking for case status we can achieve the same using SOQL query.
3. Also , you can rename few variables & move this logic in a trigger handler.

For checking case status , we can first capture the Case Ids for the feed comment and then query on the specific Case status as below :

```
Set<Case> caseIds = new Set<case>();
for(FeedComment fc: trigger.new){
    if (feedMap != null && feedMap.containsKey(fc.feedItemId) && fc.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Case.SObjectType ) {
      caseIds.add(fc.ParentId);      
    }
```

We can then check the case status in SOQL query :

```
Set<String> caseStatusSet = new Set<String>{'Waiting on Internal','Waiting on Client'};
List<Case> casesToUpdate = [SELECT Internal_Case_Status__c,Status FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIds AND Status IN :caseStatusSet];
```

Final trigger will look like :

```
trigger FeedThis on FeedComment(after insert, after update){

  Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
  Set<Id> userList = new Set<Id>();
  Set<Id> feedItemList = new Set<Id>();
  Set<String> caseStatusSet = new Set<String>{'Waiting on Internal','Waiting on Client'};

  for(FeedComment fc: trigger.new){
      feedItemList.add(fc.FeedItemId);
      userList.add(fc.InsertedById);
  }

  Map<Id, FeedItem> feedMap = new Map<id, FeedItem>([select id,InsertedById,Visibility from feedItem where Id IN :feedItemList]);
  Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id, User>([select id, usertype, name from user where ID IN :userList]);

  for(FeedComment fc: trigger.new){
    if (feedMap != null && feedMap.containsKey(fc.feedItemId) && fc.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Case.SObjectType ) {
      caseIds.add(fc.ParentId);      
    }
    
}

List<Case> casesToUpdate = [SELECT Internal_Case_Status__c,Status FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIds AND Status IN :caseStatusSet];

if(casesToUpdate != null && casesToUpdate.size() > 0) {
  for (Case caseRec : casesToUpdate) {
    caseRec.Internal_Case_Status__c = 'Pending'
  }

  update casesToUpdate;
}

}
```

Comment: Hi Rohit! This is really helpful and almost gets the job done! It still triggers the status update when the case is in ANY status not just Waiting on Internal or Waiting on Client. I do not know apex well enough for this so I really appreciate the guidance! I also get a "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(Id) from the type Set<Case>" on line 18

Comment: Updated the trigger with correct code. Please try and check now. You can start exploring Apex docs for learning it - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Is is working for you now ?

Comment: Yes it is! I have other things I would like FeedComment to automate but this is great for now! I will need to explore other options and see if there is a way to get it done myself. My company does not have many, if any, Apex educated individuals but since FeedComments are not applicable to Flows it becomes harder.

Comment: Great to know, you can accept it for someone else to refer in future.