# How do i get rid of this error. The semicolon required seems spurious. LWC javascript error: LWC1503: Parsing error: Missing semicolon

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

```js
import Email from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Email';
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class NitronsolarLogin extends LightningElement {}

email;
password;

handleUsername(event){
  this.email=event.target.value;
}

handlepassword(event){
  this.password=event.target.value;
}

handleLogin(){
  console.log("Inside Login");
  console.log("Email Value: ", this.email);
  console.log("Password Value: ", this.password);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variables and `handle*` methods need to be inside of the curly braces of `export default class NitronsolarLogin extends LightningElement`

You currently have them outside of the curly braces.